# delete original project folder after i checked it in into svn repo?

Tags: svn

should i after i have created a svn repo, import one project folder into it with "svn import" and then DELETE my original local folder thus only having it in the svn repo in the remote ubuntu server?

is this safe or should i still have a local copy for some reason (cause i wont work in that one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code is in the repository, then you're probably fine deleting the original import.  You want to check it out to get a working svn local copy anyway.  I would only delete the original import after I was sure that I had a usable working copy downloaded using `svn checkout`.

Of course, if the repository is the only place your code exists, you're going to want to be taking backups of your repository!